# Using boolean values in resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, boolean

In the application I'm working on there is a preference which can be enabled or disabled to convert all values to metric from imperial. I need to be able to save the preference even after the application is closed and reopened. The way I was thinking of going about it was to use a boolean value in a resource (.resx) file, which I could just set the value of whenever the box was checked or unchecked. Then, when the program is launched, it can simply check what the value of the resource bool is (true/false) and set the checkbox accordingly.

My problem is that when I try to use a resource of type bool or Boolean, when I check the box the application crashes and I get an error regarding memory, I believe it was a stack overflow exception.

My question is, is it just not possible to use and/or modify boolean values in a resource [.resx] file, or am I going about it incorrectly? If it's not possible, what alternative ways might there be to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Don't make us guess, and don't rely on memory. Show us the exception you're getting.

Comment: How are you setting your data back in resource file.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is your problem don't go for bool values.

Go for int or string equivalent of bool like if you choose int then 0 or 1 or

```
bool res = Convert.ToBoolean(1);
```

or

```
bool res = Convert.ToBoolean(0);
```

If you go for string then "true" or "false".

```
bool res = Convert.ToBoolean("true");
```

or

```
bool res = Convert.ToBoolean("false");
```

Comment: I actually had considered using a binary 0/1 option, but that doesn't quite feel like the 'right' way to do it. I was not aware of the Convert.ToBoolean() method, however - I will try that way...thanks!

Comment: I just tried this way and I'm having the same problem. When I try to set the resource's value, I get a StackOverflowException. Is it not possible to *set* resource values, only get them?

Answer (score 1):

Create [User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  They are easy to use and handle types for you.